# PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions error 304

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am linking parse.com with facebook: I allow my users to login with their facebook account. When they press "login with facebook" I use the [PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions...] function.

However, sometimes when using the logInInBackgroundwithReadPersmissions I get an "strange" error.code=304 back as argument in the block being called (and the user argument supplied to the block is nil).

This is my code:

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_birthday"] block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!user) {
        if (! error) {
            NSLog(@"The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        }
        else {
            //error 304 = FBSDKLoginUserMismatchErrorCode
            if(error.code==304) {
            ***what to do here???***
            }
           NSLog(@"Login failed, please try again")
        }

    }
```

Once this error happens it keeps on happening, meaning each time logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions is called (if the user tries to login again by pressing "login with facebook" again) its the same 304 error.
And this keeps on happening...

I have found that 304 means FBSDKLoginUserMismatchErrorCode and that I should log out of "Facebook" see here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/713

However I am using Parse integration, not Facebook api directly, how should I handle this error?

Comment: If you're using Parse, why are you using `PFFacebookUtils`'s `-logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions`? Use parse's login methods instead.

Comment: I believe that PFFacebookUtils logIn... is a parse method no? (PFxxx Parse Framework...)

Comment: @Schemetrical, PFFacebookUtils will combine Facebook user info into Parse user table. It's like linking Facebook user with Parse user. I think, that is what 'HixField' want.